# Failed to connect (500) to bot framework using Direct Line

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service, direct-line-botframework

We have a bot running in Azure (Web App Bot) that I'm trying to embed on a website. The bot is based of the Bot Builder V4 SDK Tamplate CoreBot v4.9.2. At first I used the `iframe` to embed the bod. This worked but didn't provide the features we need, so now im changing it to use DirectLine.

My code on the webpage looks like this:

```
<script crossorigin="anonymous"
    src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>

<div id="webchat" role="main"></div>

<script>
  (async function () {
    const res = await fetch('https://[my bot name here].azurewebsites.net/.bot/v3/directline/tokens/generate', 
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: new Headers({
          'Authorization': "Bearer [my token here]"
        })
      });
    const { token } = await res.json();

    window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
      {
        directLine: await window.WebChat.createDirectLineAppServiceExtension({
          domain: 'https://[my bot name here].azurewebsites.net/.bot/v3/directline',
          token
        })
      },
      document.getElementById('webchat')
    );

    document.querySelector('#webchat > *').focus();
  })().catch(err => console.error(err));
</script>
```

After some struggles I managed to fetch a token from `https://[my bot name here].azurewebsites.net/.bot/v3/directline`.
And I can see the chat window on my webpage, but is says `connecting` for a while then it changes to `Taking longer than usual to connect`, like this:

[image: the chat looks like this now]

In the Chrome console there is an error saying `Failed to connect Error: Connection response code 500`. When I check Chrome's Network tab I can see that the token generated completed with status 200 and that the websocket connection is open, like this:
[image]

----------EDIT---------

I just noticed that when go to `https://[my bot name here].azurewebsites.net/.bot` using a webbrowser, the resulting json is

```
{"v":"1.0.0.0.55fa54091a[some key?]","k":true,"ib":false,"ob":false,"initialized":true}
```

ib and ob should be true but are false, maybe this is part of the problem.

----------EDIT 2---------
OK so now I'm starting to go crazy.
Ashish helped me and at some point the ib and ob were true. They were true for most of yesterday. At some point yesterday they turned false for a short while (no more than 2 hours). I checked if someone had triggered the release pipeline but no recent releases. After that ib and ob magically turned true again and connecting to the direct line worked again.

Now this morning ib and ob were false again. And again no recent releases. I don't know what is causing this.

Does anybody know what's going on here or how to fix this? How do I find what causes ib and ob to be false?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance. If you need more information, just ask and I'll post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ib and ob values displayed by the *.bot endpoint are false this means the bot and the Direct Line app service extension are unable to connect to each other.

Make sure you verify below things:

1. Double check the code for using named pipes has been added to the
   bot.
2. Confirm the bot is able to start up and run at all. Useful
   tools are Test in WebChat, connecting an additional channel, remote
   debugging, or logging.
3. Restart the entire Azure App Service the bot
   is hosted within, to ensure a clean start up of all processes.

Please check [troubleshooting guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-directline-extension-net-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#troubleshooting), it seems updated today. (still old date reflected some how, not sure why)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Ib and ob are true now so that's good. I'm running into a new problem that I will try to fix myself. I'll report back if I can't figure it out.

Comment: Now ib and ob seem to randomly go false and back to true again after a while. See edit 2 in the question. I do not know what to do anymore.

Comment: @Martijn I am facing same problem some time, but after refreshing page multiple times I am able to make it working. I think [always on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/app-service/configure-common#configure-general-settings) settings in General setting area In App service configuration might causes this problem.